# Install django1.7 with Python 3.4 using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.4

I have hit a bit of a brick wall regarding the set up of django 1.7 using a virtualenv configured to Python 3.4.

I have created a Python 3.4 virtualenv using:

```
sudo virtualenv --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3.4 venv
```

I have then activated the env using:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Once in the activated virtualenv i have tried:

```
sudo pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7b1/tarball/
```

This installs django in the Python 2.7 directory and not in the virtual environment.. 
Checking with `pip freeze` shows no installed packages

I have tried downloading the zip for django 1.7 and using `python setup.py install` within the environment but still get the install occurring outside of the env and in the 2.7 directory..

Any advice or pointers on what i'm doing wrong would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Two things of note: 1) `--no-site-packages` is now a default option, so you don't need to specify it in your command; 2) Django 1.7b2 has been released with a few security fixes, so you can change your URL to https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7b2/tarball/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`sudo` is unnecessary when creating a virtualenv and when installing with pip inside a virtualenv. Try the following instead:

`$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 venv`

`$ source venv/bin/activate`

(At this point, you can check that your virtualenv is active and using python 3.4 with `which python`, which should print something like `/home/user/projects/venv/bin/python`, and `python --version`, which should print Python 3.4.x)

`$ pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7b1/tarball/`

Comment: Thanks.. I tried using Sudo as I had permission issues installing in "lib/python3.4/site-packages" and then the bin folder within the created virtualenv .. I have changed permissions and installed without sudo .. This has worked..

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is `sudo`.  The point of virtualenv is that you should not have to run anything as root -- virtualenv will set up an environment in which you can install packages as a user.  I imagine the issue is either that pip is assuming your use of sudo suggests that you want to install the package in the system package directory... or else that sudo itself is overriding the virtualenv changes to your environment in favor of root's default environment.

Create a new virtualenv without `sudo`.  Then activate it and run pip install without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

**try following**

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3 ~/.virtualenvs/py3

workon py3

pip install Django==1.7.4
```

Comment: What you are suggesting requires to have virtualenvwrapper installed.