# How do I use python 3.4 with django 1.9 in my virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, version, virtualenv, sandbox

I am trying to use python 3.4 in my django 1.9 app because python 3.5 is to new and doesn't work with packages that I need. I tried this

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 venv
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256054/install-django1-7-with-python-3-4-using-virtualenv)

but when Itried that i got this error message

```
The executable /usr/bin/python3.4 (from --python=/usr/bin/python3.4) does not exist
```

How canI make this work? thanks

I want to eventually push this to heroku server

EDIT

if I type

```
apples-MBP:myheroku ray$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

if i type python34

```
apples-MBP:myheroku ray$ python34
-bash: python34: command not found
```

if I just type python

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: What system are you on? Do you have Python 3 installed? If you're on a Linux, try typing `python`, `python3` and `python34` into the terminal and see what it says.

Comment: Well, start off by installing Python 3.4, otherwise it's pretty hard to use it. :) Sorry, I've no idea how to do that on a Mac, but I imagine it's rather similar to the Ubuntu command `sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev`. After installing Python 3.4, you can just do `virtualenv <venv-name> --python=python3.4`.

Comment: but if i ad it to my mac how will I add it to my herkoku server since it will be local to my app?

Comment: Can you not install the dependencies for the Heroku server as well? But sorry, I'm not competent to tell you about Heroku servers since I've never used one.